# Linq Query Optimization in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following query, and what I'm looking for is to optimize the `where` clause. I don't like the multiple `FirstOrDefault` uses. Is there a way to implement it with `Join` maybe, or some other way so I will be able to access the `FirstOrDefault` only once?

```
var promos = await this._context
                       .SinglePromotions
                       .Include(p => p.Rewards)
                       .Include(p => p.InAppProduct)
                       .Include(p => p.PlayerSinglePromotions)
                       .ThenInclude(sp => sp.Player)
                       .ThenInclude(pl => pl.Purchases)
                       .Where(p => p.MinimumPlayerLevel <= Player.Level && 
                                   p.Placement == placement && 
                                   p.IsActive && 
                                   (p.PlayerSinglePromotions.All(sp => sp.PlayerID != Player.ID) || 
                                    (p.PlayerSinglePromotions.FirstOrDefault(sp => sp.PlayerID == Player.ID).PurchaseAmount < p.PurchaseLimit)) &&
                                    (p.PlayerSinglePromotions.All(sp => sp.PlayerID != Player.ID) || (p.PlayerSinglePromotions.FirstOrDefault(sp => sp.PlayerID == Player.ID).Player.Purchases.Count <= p.MaxInAppPurchasesByPlayer))
                       )
                       .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: write it how you would in SQL then written the linq which represents the SQL you wrote. LinqPad is a great tool to help you verify that the linq you are writing is turning into the correct sql.

Comment: Dose this transfer into sql, I am not 100% sure can you post the sql output and the actual query that gets genetated?

Answer (score 1):

Well, probably there is a better solution, but you could replace your conditions where you use `FirstOrDefault` using `Any` extension method instead:

```
var promos = await this._context.SinglePromotions
.Include(p => p.Rewards)
.Include(p => p.InAppProduct)
.Include(p => p.PlayerSinglePromotions)
    .ThenInclude(sp => sp.Player)
    .ThenInclude(pl => pl.Purchases)
.Where(
    p => p.MinimumPlayerLevel <= Player.Level && 
    p.Placement == placement && 
    p.IsActive &&
   (p.PlayerSinglePromotions.All(sp => sp.PlayerID != Player.ID) ||
    p.PlayerSinglePromotions.Any(sp => sp.PlayerID == Player.ID 
                                   && (sp.Player.Purchases.Count <= p.MaxInAppPurchasesByPlayer || sp.PurchaseAmount < p.PurchaseLimit))))
.ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent repetition of long expression in LINQ queries by using query syntax with the [`let` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause). It's like declaring variables that contain the result of an expression. In your query two parts are repeated that can be captured in `let` variables:

```
var promos = await (
    from p in this._context.SinglePromotions
        .Include(p => p.Rewards)
        .Include(p => p.InAppProduct)
        .Include(p => p.PlayerSinglePromotions)
        .ThenInclude(sp => sp.Player)
        .ThenInclude(pl => pl.Purchases)
    let pspNotOfPlayer = p.PlayerSinglePromotions.All(sp => sp.PlayerID != Player.ID)
    let firstPromotion = p.PlayerSinglePromotions.FirstOrDefault(sp => sp.PlayerID == Player.ID)
    where
        p.MinimumPlayerLevel <= Player.Level 
        && p.Placement == placement 
        && p.IsActive
        && pspNotOfPlayer || firstPromotion.PurchaseAmount < p.PurchaseLimit
        && pspNotOfPlayer || firstPromotion.Player.Purchases.Count <= p.MaxInAppPurchasesByPlayer
    select p
    )
    .ToListAsync();
```

In many cases this will not only make the code more readable but also improve the generated SQL because repetitive subqueries can be replaced by `CROSS APPLY` clauses.

Comment: Sql optimization engine tends to handle this sort of stuff well so I am not sure how much better in regards with performance it will be, best way to see is to measure it. And is first or default supported in ef core?

Comment: @FilipCordas True, and yes, `FirstOrDefault()` is supported.

Comment: probably just me but I found EF core to frustrate me because you don't see what query is not supported until you look at the output console and see that it just pulled everything in memory and did the query locally.

Comment: @FilipCordas Not just you. So far to I think it's impossible to use EF core for enterprise applications because not all of the most common LINQ query operations are supported. Esp. grouping is a problem when it comes to server-side operation.